# auto generating unique username to new non null column

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl

I have an existing table `user_accounts` and want to add a new column `username` that has to be unique and non nullable. For the existing users I recognize I have to populate the column with data. I want to populate the column such that it would be like 'username1', 'username2' ..... for each row. I want to do something like this:

```
BEGIN;
i =0;
ALTER TABLE user_accounts ADD COLUMN username character varying(80);
UPDATE mytable SET mycolumn = username + i;
i++;
ALTER TABLE user_accounts ALTER COLUMN username SET NOT NULL;
COMMIT;
```

^^ is the following possible in a postgres ddl?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a unique id in each row, you can do:

```
update user_accounts
    set mycolumn = 'username' || seqnum;
    from (select ua.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
          from user_accounts ua
         ) ua
    where ua.useraccountid = user_accounts.useraccountid;
```